# Using global variables in calculations

Tags: c, global-variables, variable-assignment

I'm trying to do the following, where I assign my global variable to a local variable:

```
#define DECK_SIZE = 52
...
int *numberOfDecks;
scanf("%d", &numberOfDecks);
int shoeSize = *numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE;
```

It's been a while since I programmed anything in C, but to my recollection this should be possible?

Answer (score 3):

Your primary problem is that `numberOfDecks` should be an `int`, not an `int *`.  If it must be an `int *`, you also need to provide an `int` somewhere for it to point at.

Fixed code:

```
#define DECK_SIZE 52
...
int numberOfDecks;
if (scanf("%d", &numberOfDecks) != 1)
    ...handle format error...
int shoeSize = numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE;
```

Or:

```
#define DECK_SIZE 52
...
int  actualNumberOfDecks;
int *numberOfDecks = &actualNumberOfDecks;
if (scanf("%d", numberOfDecks) != 1)
    ...handle format error...
int shoeSize = *numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE;
```

But I think the second version is not as sensible as the first; there'd have to be a compelling (but as yet unstated) reason for doing that.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
#define DECK_SIZE 52
```

And your int *numberOfDecks should be

```
int numberOfDecks
```

Comment: Been trying to, but didn't have 15 reputation points until now :)

Comment: @kensing Thanks for the upvote :-) but to accept the answer you just have to click the check mark below the place where you clicked to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *numberOfDecks;
scanf("%d", &numberOfDecks);
```

Since numberOfDecks is already a pointer, you don't need to take the address of it. Just pass `numberOfDecks` to scanf. (Or make it not a pointer and modify the rest of the code likewise.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `define` is wrong, it should be

```
#define DECK_SIZE 52
```

You also have a pointer that is not initialized and that could be considered a bad practice.

EDIT:

You also have problems on your argument for the scanf as stated in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Errors:

- macro contains `=`
- `numberofdecks` is uninitialized pointer
- result of `scanf` ignored

Possible fix:

```
const int DECK_SIZE = 52;
...
int numberOfDecks;
if (scanf("%d", &numberOfDecks) == 1)
{
    int shoeSize = numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `numberOfDecks` variable is of the wrong type. You have made it a pointer, and the `scanf` call will write a value to *the pointer*, effectively changing where it points. You just want a plain integer there.

The definition of the DECK_SIZE macro is good except for one thing: macros are straight-up replacements, and the syntax doesn't use an '=' so the '=' is actually a part of the macro. That means you're asking the compiler to replace "DECK_SIZE" everywhere with "= 52". You'll want to get rid of the '=' sign: `#define DECK_SIZE 52`

Hope that helps :-)